# When travelling in the direction of light, what is my relative velocity?

Tags: speed-of-light, relativity

If suppose I am traveling in the same direction as that of light, the relative velocity I am traveling with is speed of light + my speed in the direction of light. Is this correct?

Does this have something to do with "Principle of Relativity"?

Comment: No, the light will be traveling at the speed of light in your reference frame.  Light always travels at the speed of light regardless of reference frame.

Comment: As Greg told the speed of light in any frame of reference will be same. This is most crucial underlying principle of special theory of relativity. For first time readers it is always astonishing because it contradicts common sense. The reason behind this is actually that _time_ and _space_ are not absolute and we(Newtonian physics students) have to reanalyze basic understanding of physics from scratch once again.

Comment: on earth we are not moving in the direction of light or opposite to it. we are perhaps moving perpendicular to light

Answer (score 2):

Your relative velocity can not be determined.

Lets say you have a space ship that is very long, say 300,000 km long. If light passes from one end to the other, say rear to front, your clocks will tell you that it took 1 second for the light to cover this full length since the speed of light is 300,000 km/s. If again light passes from one end to the other, say this time front to rear, once again your clocks will tell you that it took 1 second for the light to cover the full length.

Next, if you start your rocket engines and head off to the right and accelerate to what you would assume to be a high velocity due to the G forces at work, you will still measure a time period of 1 second for any light to pass from the rear to front, or front to rear.

Or, if you had started your rocket engines and headed off to the left instead, and accelerate to a high velocity, you will still measure a time period of 1 second for any light to pass from the rear to front, or front to rear.

The fun part, is knowing exactly why this occurs.

Comment: I think it's important to state that _during_ the said acceleration, you wouldn't measure 1 second. Only when you stop accelerating and continue at an ever-so-high speed, you'd measure 1 second again.

Comment: pela - Yes, that is why I stated "accelerate to", with "accelerate to" meaning "to reach" a high velocity.

Comment: Yeah okay, I read [past tense] it as it was during the acceleration. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks pela for your kind reply. Sometimes I think the English language is a real pain.

Comment: our brains cannot imagine what can happen in 1 second when light has moved 3 lakh kms.